# Change Background color of 2D sheets of Autodesk Forge using Javascript

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

How to set a background color in 2D view of autodesk forge file to a specific Room on a floor or level using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a background color in 2D, you have to two programmable options...

viewer.setBackgroundColor(...);
viewerImp.toggleSwapBlackAndWhite(true/false);

You can find the API details for setBackgroundColor here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/

and line2191 toggle blackwhite here:
autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/src_application_Viewer3D.js.html

Here is a working example...

1. Open this URL in a recent version of chrome:
   https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3d.html?svf=https://lmv-models.s3.amazonaws.com/2d_model/primaryGraphics.f2d
2. Open up the debug console and type these two options:

NOP_VIEWER.impl.toggleSwapBlackAndWhite(true);
NOP_VIEWER.setBackgroundColor(255,255,0,0,255,255);

The result should give you a clue to what is possible with just the api.

This is specific to the web viewer.  Is that what you were looking for ?